# Prevent html form submit while uploading file in jQuery-File-Upload plugin

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-file-upload

I have a html form, as a second element of form, I am uploading files with [jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)
, then below it, there are some html elements. At the end of the html form there is a submit button. When I click "Browse file" button and select the file for uploading, all of html form is submitted as the submit button clicked. This situation is causing problems, because below the "Browse file" button there are some html form elements and they are empty. Here are my codes:

```
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    var url = 'control.php?upload_file';
    $('#file_upload').fileupload({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'text',
        done: function (e, data) {
            $("#result").html(data.result);
        },
        progressall: function (e, data) {
            $('#dosya_durum').show();
        }
    });
});
```

I did not manage the problem. Could you help me?

Comment: can you please also post your HTML-code?

Comment: disable submit button until file is not uploaded.when file is uploaded then remove disable attribute :)

Comment: I am also having same issue. Did you able to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

In the form causing the issue could you not use `onsubmit="return false;"`

Comment: Also, from my understanding of your question, you have a form within another form, which I don't believe is valid html practice

Comment: No, I have only one html form. While file uploading, form is submitted in the same time.

Comment: I couldn't leave a comment below there post due to insufficient reputation but thanks for the advice.